# How can effect of electromagnetic radiation on human sperm be explained physically?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, biology, microwaves

I am not sure if this question belongs here. If it doesn't belong here, feel free to remove it (and maybe tell me where to post this instead?).

I have been researching the question of whether electromagnetic radiation emitted from things like cell towers or wifi access points can be harmful to the human body. I have found many sources **<sup>1</sup>** that state that there is no health risk. The frequencies these devices use are simply too low to pose a risk. That makes sense to me, and I have no reason to doubt that conclusion.

But then I found several sources **<sup>2</sup>** that referenced a Japanese study that apparently found that WiFi radiation can actually negatively affect human sperm.

My question is, can the results of the study be explained using physics? What is damaging the sperm physically speaking? What am I missing?

I also want to make it clear that I am not a skeptic of science in any form. I am simply interested in this subject and would like to learn something.

**Footnotes:**

**<sup>1</sup>** Sources claiming WiFi and cell tower radiation is harmless:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4pxw4tYeCU
2. https://www.theguardian.com/technology/askjack/2012/sep/27/wi-fi-health-risks
3. https://www.howtogeek.com/234817/dont-worry-wi-fi-isnt-dangerous/
4. https://www.fda.gov/radiation-emitting-products/cell-phones/do-cell-phones-pose-health-hazard

**<sup>2</sup>** The study claiming electromagnetic radiation is affecting sperm: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4503846/

Comment: This belongs to [biology.se].

Comment: That is a horrible article, which I have no faith in. For example, nowhere does it indicate the radiated power. Better on Skeptics SE perhaps.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie at my university we have a section called Biophysics and medical physics. The biophysicists specifically deal with cells' reactions to radiation, electromagnetic or otherwise. This seems to be what the question is about, though the Japanese paper certainly leaves much to be desired.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://biology.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I will make a very general comment without having read the linked paper. I'm not by any means endorsing its conclusions.

When people talk about EM radiation from WiFi, cell phones, etc. not being harmful, they are mostly referring to the fact that this radiation is too low-energy to be ionizing, so it won't damage cells or DNA in the same way that, e.g., UV light from the sun can. The only way that a radio frequency wave like a WiFi signal can harm is for the power to be so large that it literally cooks you, and practically that just doesn't happen. However, sperm cells are well-known to be extremely sensitive to temperature, so much so that even our body's temperature is too high for them, and they must be stored away from the rest of the body. For that reason, it is at least plausible to me that sperm cells could be damaged by radio frequency radiation at lower power than is needed to affect other cells. To do any kind of careful study of this, it would be very important to understand how much power is actually being delivered to the body as EM radiation.

Comment: I looked at the paper and it seems the poor rats were in a cage of about 2x1x1 meters (smaller) and there were two megaherz antenae at the two sides . The rats were being cooked imo.